# How to compile an Android project with command line

Tags: android

I have an Android project with java code and jni code.
It has an 'Android.mk', how can I compile the project?

I tried 
1. go to the top of my android repository
2. source build/envsetup.sh
3. mmm {path to the top level of my project}

but I don't see my project get compiled.

Any idea?

Comment: are you trying to build a project from the Android source or just an APK?

Comment: To build your jni code, use `ndk-build`, which is located in $NDK_HOME.